# Spring Setter Injection on shadowed fields

Tags: java, spring

I want to shadow a variable and change its type from boolean to string in its child class. Yet, the setter injection fails. I know it is a bad practice to use shadowing, however I would like to know if it is possible and how.

Example what I would like to do:

```
public class A {

    public boolean field;

    @SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
    public boolean isField() {

        return field;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
    public void setField(boolean field) {

        this.field = field;
    }
}
```

I want to shadow the attribute 'field' to be a String in the subclass.

```
public class B extends A {

    private String field;

    @SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
    public String getField() {

        return field;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
    public void setField(String field) {

        this.field = field;
    }
}
```

I get an exception that the setter Injection does not work:

org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [boolean] for property 'field'

```
<bean id="exampleBean" class="B" >
                <property name="field" value="value"/>
            </bean>
```

Comment: have you configured a 'bean' for parent class 'A'. Because sometimes what happens subclass instance won't get created unless you create a bean for parent class. Though I'm not sure about it, but you can give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Though I haven't tested it. But you can try the following way.

```
<bean id="beanA" class="A">
    <property name="field" value="false"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="beanB" parent="beanA" class="B">
    <property name="field" value="anyValue"></property>
</bean>
```

Let me know If it works for you.

**Edit-**

Please go through the [Bean definition inheritance](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-child-bean-definitions) doc.

I have tested the example for shadowed field that you are using. You must have to configure a bean for parent class as well, because if you only configure bean for child class, you would get exception below -

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'helloWorld' is defined
```

I don't know what you are trying to accomplish using so-called shadowed fields. But here I have created a working example which might help you. Check it out.

**MainApp.java**

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

        HelloWorld hw = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");
        System.out.println("Is message:" + hw.isMsg());

        HelloCountry hc = (HelloCountry) context.getBean("helloCountry");
        System.out.println("Message:" + hc.getMessage());

    }
}

class HelloWorld {
    private boolean message;

       public void setMessage(boolean message){
          this.message  = message;
       }

       public boolean isMsg(){
           return message;
       }
}

class HelloCountry extends HelloWorld {
    private String message;

       public void setMessage(String message){
          this.message  = message;
       }

       public String getMessage(){
           return message;
       }
}
```

**Beans.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

   <!-- A parent class bean must be defined to create its instance -->
   <bean id = "helloWorld" class = "com.example.HelloWorld">
      <property name = "message" value = "false"/>
   </bean>

   <bean id = "helloCountry" class = "com.example.HelloCountry">
      <property name = "message" value = "Hello Country!!!"/>
   </bean>

</beans>
```

**Output**

[image]

**Note**-

You would get a below exception only when you pass any value other than `boolean` in your parent `bean`. In your case, your data type of child class field is matching with the injected bean value, but you must have to have a configured `bean` for parent class as well. In short this is how It works `Dependency Injection` in case of `Inheritance`.-

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'boolean' for property 'message';
```

Let me know If it was helpful.